# Run a command many times in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a scenario in Javascript which runs and it gives me a result in Console. In this scenario, I need to insert 5 times a pair of different coordinates (for each time). If I copy-paste the same code 5 times, with different coordinates (which they are inserted in different variables each time), it doesn't run. Below, I put the same code twice with different coordinates as I try the same thing in Jsfiddle.

```
//first pair of coordinates:

let x= 38.041242 ,y= 23.679595

let myString = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=${x},${y}&size=300x300&pitch=90`
getBase64FromImageUrl(myString);

console.log(x,y);


//second pair of coordinates:

let z= 38.041310 ,f= 23.679684

let myString = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=${z},${f}&size=300x300&pitch=90`
getBase64FromImageUrl(myString);

console.log(z,f);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? You cant define myString twice so try using myString1 and myString2.

Comment: ^^ Probably that's the issue.  Only use `let` the first time and it may fix your problem.

Comment: @ThatBrianDude thank you so much!!Have a nice day!!

Comment: @Archer thank you so much!!Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect as @ThatBrianDude and @Archer have already stated that you are getting an error because you are defining the variable myString more than once.  I would also recommend you create an array of objects instead of copy pasting the code over and over.

```
// Array of coordinates to run through.
let coordinates = [{x: 38.041242, y: 23.679595, {x: 38.041310, y: 23.679684}];

// List of images.
let images = coordinates.map((coordinate) => {

  // URL based on coordinates.
  return getBase64FromImageUrl(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=${coordinate.x},${coordinate.y}&size=300x300&pitch=90`);
});
```

Comment: Happy to help.  Sorry for so many edits.  I just kept coming up with ways to make it more closely resolve your problem.  You also have a wonderful day!